# Displaying Images when hovering over point in Plotly scatter plot in python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to plot something similar to the gif below using plotly, where an image is displayed when hovering on a point in the scatter plot, but I just don't know where to start.
Is it even possible to use plotly or will I have to use Bokeh?

[image: Image appearing on hovering in scatterplot]

Comment: Do you want to display the image inside the tooltip, or outside/next to the plot? For the former, this Github issue is current tracking progress in adding the feature to Plotly.py: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1323

For the latter, this Dash app shows how to do it with callbacks: https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps/tree/main/apps/dash-tsne

Comment: @xhlulu, thanks for the informative reply. It is indeed the former (inside the tooltip). I'm glad to know that they are currently working on it.

Comment: Available through dash, see https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1323#issuecomment-933646972

Answer (score 2):

With `Dash 2.0` this can be achieved by the `dcc.Tooltip` component setting the attributes `show` (whether the tooltip is shown), `bbox` (bounding box coordinates) and `children` (content of the tooltip including the image).

If you take a look at the examples from the [`dcc.Tooltip` documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/tooltip), you will notice some key points:

- Turn off the hover effects from native `plotly.js` in your figure:

```
# Assuming fig is your plotly figure
fig.update_traces(hoverinfo="none", hovertemplate=None)
```

- The callback is triggered by the `hoverData` attribute of `dcc.Graph` that includes the figure and outputs the above described `show`, `bbox` and `children`:

```
# Assuming app is your Dash app
@app.callback(Output("graph-tooltip", "show"), Output("graph-tooltip", "bbox"),
              Output("graph-tooltip", "children"), Input("graph-basic-2", "hoverData"),
)
def display_hover(hoverData):
    # ...
    pt = hoverData["points"][0]
    bbox = pt["bbox"]
    # ...
    # img_src is your image, e.g. from URL or b64 encoded
    children = [
        html.Div([
            html.Img(src=img_src, style={"width": "100%"}),
            html.P("Tooltip text"),
        ])
    ]
    return True, bbox, children
```